# using libcurl to call Amazon s3 RESTful service

Tags: c++, rest, amazon-s3, libcurl

I am writing a piece of c++ code with libcurl to call Amazon s3 RESTful service as follows:

```
void SampleOfS3Get()
{
    //Init curl 
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    CURL* curlHandle = curl_easy_init();

    //Init var
    char* curlErrStr = (char*)malloc(CURL_ERROR_SIZE);
    curl_slist* httpHeaders = NULL; 
    const char* date = getDateForHeader();

    httpHeaders = curl_slist_append(httpHeaders, "Host: s3.amazonaws.com");//Set Host
    httpHeaders = curl_slist_append(httpHeaders, date);//Set Date
    httpHeaders = curl_slist_append(httpHeaders, getAuthorizationForHeader("AKIAISZALBSY-----XGQ","tIzCC----------/Jsn5KqTfuCAWyD1eyeOKStx0",date));//Set authorization

    //Execute
    if(curlHandle) 
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, CURLOPT_STDERR);//Set verbose mode
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);//Set automaticallly redirection
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,1);//Set max redirection times
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, curlErrStr);//Set error buffer
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);//Set http version 1.1
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, httpHeaders);//Set headers
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://s3.amazonaws.com/");//Set URL

        CURLcode curlErr = curl_easy_perform(curlHandle);//Perform

        if(curlErr) 
        {
            cout<<curl_easy_strerror(curlErr)<<endl;
        }

        //Output redirection url
        if(CURLE_OK == curlErr) 
        {
            char *url;
            curlErr = curl_easy_getinfo(curlHandle, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, &url);

            if((CURLE_OK == curlErr) && url)
                cout<<"CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL: "<<url<<endl;
        }

        /* Clean-up libcurl */
        curl_global_cleanup();
    }
}
```

This function calls the "GET SERVICE" to get the list of all buckets for a specified user.But the HTTP response of this HTTP request turns out to be "a temporary redirect to http://aws.amazon.com/s3" with http state code 307.

Then I find it in the official document which implies that caller should handle the redirection himself,so I add CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION attribute as well.Then the result turns out to be a webpage content of amazon s3.

More details:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html?r=1821
When I use the example accessID and accessKey in the above link,i get the right signature as "Example List All My Buckets" shows.It confused me that the server redirect my request instead of returning the expected all bucket list of my own(using my own accessID and accessKey).

Somebody encounter the similar problem like mine?SOS...

Answer (score 1):

You should really start by reading http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAPI.html first, as your current code contains many issues. Especially make sure you fully understand how [Signing and Authenticating REST Requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html?r=1821) work.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.In my code function getDateForHeader() returns date like "Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2007 21:20:27 GMT" and function getAuthorizationForHeader(const char*, const char*, const char*) returns authorization as "Authorization: AWS AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:lx3byBScXR6KzyMaifNkardMwNk=", and i've proved hmac_sha1 and encode64 right as [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html?r=1821] shows.I doubt whether it's caused by incorrect header or the wrong way i call.I will be grateful if u can give more advice:)

Comment: Take a look at my project: [RiofS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs), there is a file `src/http_connection.c` which generates Auth string. Read it and you should get the idea.

Comment: Surely it takes time to review your code and find out the solution.Actually in my spare time i'm developing a c++ tool(https://github.com/honeybear/S3cppsdk) encapsulating the s3 RESTful api, which is the first target of this project. Anyway thank u for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This small C++  project seems to do cURL based File PUTs to AWS S3.

with CMake, one can generate VC++ Project/solutions and build it into .LIB static library, or, use it as source code, in your VC++  Solution.

I used it in a VC++ 2013 MFC Project.

Hope it helps.

https://github.com/cedricve/AWS-S3-Cpp-REST-API